# how to hide custom UIButton in uitableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am using a custom UItablecell for rows in one of my uitableviews. However, the customtabelcell has a UIButton that I would like to hide in the UItableview display. The custom tablecell was designed in IB. I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to hide the uibutton:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
       {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customTableCell1";
        customTableCell1* myOrderCell1 = (customTableCell1*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (myOrderCell1 == nil) 
           {
            NSLog(@"Cell created");

            NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customTableCell1"
                                                                owner:nil
                                                              options:nil];

            for(id currentObj in nibObjects)
               {
                if ([currentObj isKindOfClass:[customTableCell1 class]] ) 
                   {
                    myOrderCell1 = (customTableCell1 *)currentObj;
                   }
               }    
           }
        myOrderCell1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        myOrderCell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        **myOrderCell1.AddToCartBtn.hidden = YES;
        myOrderCell1.AddToCartBtn.enabled = NO**;

        return myOrderCell1;
       }
```

Does anyone have some idea as to what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you set the button outlet in IB?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Thanks :)